# Customize file extension colors for ls output in Cshell

Tags: linux, shell, csh, ls

I know that there is an option for ls:

```
ls --color
```

...that will display different colors for files, directories, links, etc. in c-shell, but i'm wondering if there's a way to ***customize*** the output of `ls` so that files that match `*.foo` come up as red, files that match `*.bar` come up as green, etc. I would expect there is some way to set this up in my startup file .cshrc. Any clean solutions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, and better suited for unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible using LS_COLORS variable. You could define it as below:

```
setenv LS_COLORS "${LS_COLORS}:*.foo=00;31:*.bar=00;32:"
```

This variable is used to customize the way ls command shows color of the particular file. It has a pattern like:

```
*.foo=<Attribute>;<foreground text color>;<background color>


Attribute values:
00=none
01=bold
04=underscore
05=blink
07=reverse
08=concealed

Text color codes:

30=black
31=red
32=green
33=yellow
34=blue
35=magenta
36=cyan
37=white

Background color codes:

40=black
41=red
42=green
43=yellow
44=blue
45=magenta
46=cyan
47=white
```

Comment: Note that this works with the `ls-F` builtin, and *not* necessarily with `/bin/ls`. GNU `ls` does do pick up on this, I think, but BSD `ls` doesn't (that includes OSX).

Comment: It's not for GNU as such, it's for `ls-F`, GNU `ls` *happens* to use a syntax that is either very similar or the same.

Comment: hmm if you try ls --color-tty with LS_COLORS is what will apply the change is what i know